# Xampp Wordpress Install - Mysql Update: Deprecated Extension

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to set up a local developer environment with Xampp which will be using WordPress. 
On trying to install WordPress to my local environment, the following message is shown on the WordPress Welcome/Install page:

> **Deprecated:** mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and
>   will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\wcto2013\wp-includes\wp-db.php** on line **1142**

I'm a bit of a beginner so a few of the concepts are a bit beyond me at this point. I have searched online but I'm not sure how I update to Mysqli or PDO, which is better/easier or where to make these updates. I have just started dabbling in more complex backend site development but I still don't know a whole lot about PHP or Mysql as I mostly only use html and css.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Thank you both - two awesome answers even my nooby self can understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`…I'm not sure how I update to Mysqli or PDO…`

You are good, you needn't to do anything.

Extension `MySQL` is depracted as of PHP5.5, which your version of XAMPP uses.

Unfortunately, WordPress still uses this `MySQL`, which makes it impossible to run under mentioned php5.5.

Just download a little bit older version of XAMPP, which uses at most php5.4, be it [`xampp 1.8.2`](http://www.apachefriends.org/download.php?xampp-win32-1.8.2-2-VC9-installer.exe).

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress uses outdated functions, since [mysql_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) has officially been depreciated and will be removed in the future. So, it's a reminder of that (but you are good to go) and you should think about [Using Alternative Databases](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Alternative_Databases#Solutions/). To, use/enable [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) in your `WordPress` installation you can [follow this](http://epilogica.info/articles/how-to/wordpress/installing-sqlite-PDO.htm) which talks about [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/pdo-for-wordpress/) (PDO (SQLite) For WordPress), which enables `WP` to use databases supported by PHP's PDO abstraction layer.